# MS Excel VBA Reading Outlook Calendar Items Very Slowly

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm in the process of writing code to pull my own Outlook calendar, as well as some shared calendars into an MS Excel spreadsheet. However, I'm finding that my script is running very slowly. I've found that it takes about 1-2 minutes to load a months worth of events from my own calendar and about 10-20 minutes to load events from the same time period from a shared calendar.

I've noticed that my script can load my personal calendar both when I'm on and offline. However, I will get a run-time error at the when I call ".GetSharedDefaultFolder" if I am not connected to the internet. In addition, if I disconnect my internet while looping through items in a shared calendar, I will also get a run-time error. My best guess at the moment is that the majority of my speed issues are due to the fact that Outlook is checking the exchange server for each item, one at a time (I'm pretty sure this is happening).

Does anybody have a good idea of how to solve this problem? I'd like to speed up my code so it doesn't take ~45 minutes to run my script. I have a hard time believing that Outlook does not store the most recent version of a shared calendar on my laptop. I also don't see why I shouldn't be able to call some function to download the entire calendar and then loop through the items without needing to separately request each item from the server.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to post your code.

Comment: What @Mr.Mascaro said, plus, if you have functioning code, that just needs to be improved for performance, you'd be better served posting at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What code do you use? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to fix the problem by enabling the "Download shared folders" property in MS Outlook. This reduced program execution time from 45 minutes down to 7 minutes.

Directions on how to enable the "Download shared folders" property:
http://www.msoutlook.info/question/414

Note: To find the Account Settings button in Outlook 2013, you have to navigate to the "File" menu.

Comment: It would still be a good idea to post your code- there are quite a few ways to speed things up even if your folders are cached, e.g. MAPIFolder.GetTable